# Alexa (amazon) calling server to custom Alexa skill webservice - firewall needs opened

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I need to host my own webservice end point, but cannot find what the address is calling my custom Alexa Skill webservice endpoint.  I need this to be able to open u the firewall to accept the calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a web service... So you need to open port 443 by default. But I believe your service URL on the Alexa setup UI can contain any custom ports as long as it is an SSL endpoint.

For testing, you can use the [Bespoken Tools](https://bespoken.tools) or [nGrok](https://ngrok.com) to proxy back to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I needed to now where the call from Amazon is coming from to be able to add it to the firewall pass through.  It is coming from *.amazonaws.com